# Как найти элемент в дереве по data через js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть в переменной значение `al`. Как мне получить его номер `data-dial-code = 355` ну или номер `+350` со спана. Нужна как-то найти `li` с `data-county-code по значению al`. Это вообще возможно ?

```html
<li class="country" data-dial-code="355" data-country-code="al">
    <span class="country-name">Albania</span>
    <span class="dial-code">+355</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var code = prompt(); // Для примера вводим нужный код
console.log($('[data-country-code="' + code + '"]').data('dial-code'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="country" data-dial-code="355" data-country-code="al">
    <span class="country-name">Albania</span>
    <span class="dial-code">+355</span>
  </li>
  <li class="country" data-dial-code="7" data-country-code="ru">
    <span class="country-name">Russia</span>
    <span class="dial-code">+7</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `.data('dial-code')`

Comment: Спасибо большое )

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста:)